# How to create (sub) Classes based of user input, without switch cases?

Tags: java, class, user-input

I would like to ask the user for a unit to add to their army:

```
public class addToArmy {
  public void addUnit(ArrayList<Unit> units, String commander) {
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Choose a unit");
      String input = Battlefield.scanner.next();
      switch (input) {
        case "Soldier":
          Soldier sd = new Soldier(commander);
          units.add(sd);
          return;
      
        case "Medic":
          Medic md = new Medic(commander);
          units.add(md);
          return;

        default:
          System.out.println("Not a valid unit");
    
    return;
  }
}
// Soldier and Medic inherits from abstract class Unit.
```

While I can use switch statements, if I want to keep adding different types of Units, I would need to keep extending. I intend to have at least 20 units, so this is not optimal.

Is there a way to add units based on user input without making a bunch of case statements?

Comment: What's "not optimal" about having 20 cases?

Comment: You can define a `Map<String, Function<String, Unit>>` and look them up by name.

Comment: @Sweeper what I mean is, it'd be inefficient to hardcode 20 cases in this way. I do have a draft of ~200 separate units, but I'm building the game with a smaller size for now. If I want to code 200 units this way, it'd be easy to make mistakes as well (forgetting a unit somewhere, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a different class for each one, you will have to have some point at which an instance of one of 20 different classes can be created.

You can make your case statement shorter by using a case expression, if you are on a recent version of Java:

```
                Unit u = switch (input) {
                    case "Soldier" -> new Soldier();
                    case "Medic" -> new Medic();
                    default -> null;
                };
                if (u == null) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid unit name '" + input + "'");
                } else {
                    units.add(u)
                }
```

If your `addUnit` method is the only place in your code where you need to map from the unit type as a string to some operation, I would go with what you have, otherwise you could implement something more general.

You can use `enum`s to map from a String to an enum value:

```
class Unit { ... }
class Soldier extends Unit { ... }
class Medic extends Unit { ... }
public enum UnitType {
    Soldier(Soldier.class),
    Medic(Medic.class);

    private final Class<? extends Unit> clazz;


    UnitType(Class<? extends Unit> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<? extends Unit> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String unitType = "Soldier";
        String commander = "Fred";
        Unit u = UnitType.valueOf(unitType).getClazz().getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(commander);
    }
}
```

In the above code I'm cheating by assuming that every unit type is a valid Java identifier -- "Armoured Car" wouldn't work, because it has a space in it, and you can't create an enum value with the name `Armoured Car`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic inheritance example.
It should provide good scalability, if you plan on creating multiple *Unit* sub-classes.

You can create a *parseString* method, for the *Unit* class, which will return the corresponding sub-class.

```java
/** @return null on invalid string */
static Unit parseString(String string, String commander) {
    return switch (string.toLowerCase()) {
        case "soldier" -> new Soldier(commander);
        case "medic" -> new Medic(commander);
        default -> null;
    };
}
```

And, for your input, you can just invoke the *parseString*.
Additionally, I have this exit when an empty value is entered.

```java
public void addUnit(List<Unit> units, String commander) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean exit = false;
    String string;
    Unit unit;
    do {
        string = scanner.nextLine();
        if (string.isEmpty()) exit = true;
        else {
            unit = Unit.parseString(string, commander);
            if (unit == null) System.out.println("Not a valid unit");
            else units.add(unit);
        }
    } while (!exit);
}
```

Here is an example input and output.

```
Choose a unit
soldier
Choose a unit
abc
Not a valid unit
Choose a unit
soldier
Choose a unit
medic
Choose a unit
```

And, the *units* list would contain the following.

```
[Soldier, Soldier, Medic]
```

Here is the complete code.

```java
public void addUnit(List<Unit> units, String commander) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean exit = false;
    String string;
    Unit unit;
    do {
        System.out.println("Choose a unit");
        string = scanner.nextLine();
        if (string.isEmpty()) exit = true;
        else {
            unit = Unit.parseString(string, commander);
            if (unit == null) System.out.println("Not a valid unit");
            else units.add(unit);
        }
    } while (!exit);
}

static class Unit {
    String commander;

    Unit(String commander) {
        this.commander = commander;
    }

    /** @return null on invalid string */
    static Unit parseString(String string, String commander) {
        return switch (string.toLowerCase()) {
            case "soldier" -> new Soldier(commander);
            case "medic" -> new Medic(commander);
            default -> null;
        };
    }

    private boolean isSoldier() {
        return this instanceof Soldier;
    }

    private boolean isMedic() {
        return this instanceof Medic;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

static class Soldier extends Unit {
    Soldier(String commander) {
        super(commander);
    }
}

static class Medic extends Unit {
    Medic(String commander) {
        super(commander);
    }
}
```